# Deploying a dual-backend site

Tags: node.js, flask, openai-api

I'm working on a project. The backend is made on flask but one component (Goggle Maps WebGL) is based on Nodejs. So right now, to run the application, I run flask backend with app.py and then Node backend with npm run. Note that we have a Postgres database. However, now I want to deploy my project. I need suggestions for how to go about it. Which deployment sites support such projects? How can I deploy these dual backends.

I'm deploying directly from my git repo. But I'm also using OpenAI API. How do I pass my API key without exposing it on Git? My git repo is public. https://github.com/Hamna2023/dastaan_test

I tried deploying on Render.com with flask commands.